# Scala ith order statistic

Tags: debugging, scala

I just began coding for an algorithms class I'm taking, and I'm still very much learning the basics of Scala (and screwing up frequently). The assignment is to create a program that computes the ith order statistic of an array. My problem is what I've written below compiles and runs, prints "Selecting element "+which+" from amongst the values [Array]", and then stalls out. There are no error messages. I'm sure there are several errors in the code below. In the interest of full disclosure, this is a homework assignment. I appreciate any help.

Edit: Thanks for the tips, I edited some things. I now think that select is looking at smaller and smaller portions of the array, but the code still doesn't work. It now spits out the right answer ~25% of the time, and does the same thing the rest of the time.

```
object hw3v2 { 

  // 
  // partition 
  // 
  // this is the code that partitions 
  // our array, rearranging it in place 
  // 

  def partition(a: Array[Int], b: Int, c: Int): Int = { 

    val x:Int = a(c) 
    var i:Int = b

    for (j <- b to c-1)
      if (a(j) <= x) {
        i += 1
        a(i) = a(j)
        a(j) = a(i)

      }

    a(i+1) = a(c)
    a(c) = a(i+1)
    i + 1
  }

  def select(a: Array[Int], p: Int, r: Int, i: Int): Int = {

    if (p == r)
      a(0)

    else {
      val q = partition(a, p, r)
      val j = q - p + 1
      if (i <= j)
        select(a, p, q, i)
      else
        select(a, q+1, r, i-j)
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val which = args(0).toInt

    val values: Array[Int] = new Array[Int](args.length-1);
    print("Selecting element "+which+" from amongst the values ")
    for (i <- 1 until args.length) {
      print(args(i) + (if (i<args.length-1) {","} else {""}));
      values(i-1) = args(i).toInt;
    }
    println();

    println("==> "+select(values, 0, values.length-1, which))
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example of an input and the expected output? Maybe you want something like `Seq(3, 1, 5, 2, 1).sorted.apply(k)` for the kth order statistic of the sequence?

Comment: Oops, just saw that comment a bit too late. I also guess that this is what the OP wants...

Answer (score 1):

I implore you, try to write more like this:

```
def partition(a: Array[Int], b: Int, c: Int): Int = {
  val x: Int = a(c)
  var i: Int = b - 1

  for (j <- b to c - 1)
    if (a(j) <= x) {
      i += 1
      val hold = a(i)
      a(i) = a(j)
      a(j) = hold
    }

  a(i + 1) = a(c)
  a(c) = a(i + 1)
  i + 1
}

def select(i: Int, a: Array[Int]): Int =
  if (a.length <= 1)
    a(0)
  else {
    val q = partition(a, 0, a.length - 1)
    if (i <= q)
      select(i, a)
    else
      select(i - q, a)
  }

def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val which = args(0).toInt

  printf("Selecting element %s from amongst the values %s%n".format(which, args.mkString(", ")))

  val values = args map(_.toInt)
  printf("%nb ==> %d%n", select(which, values))
}
```

To the best of my knowledge, this is the equivalent of your original code.

Answer (score 1):

Your exit condition in `select` is that the Array `a` must have a length less or equal to 1. However I cannot see anything that would every change the length of your Array. Thus, the recursive calls to `select` loop infinitely. I can only guess: Since it seems that your goal is that `select` operates on a different Array each time, you must pass a modified Array as input. Thus my guess would be that `partition` should return both an `Int` and a modified `Array`.

### Update

In case "ith order statistic" refers to the "ith" smallest element in your Array, why don't you just do the following?

```
a.sorted.apply(i)
```